# Getting Hashtable keys in intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, collections, extension-methods, hashtable

I am using hashtable that contains around 60 key,value pairs.
for assigning the value based on key to any control in my page i  have to explicitly type the keyname.

For example:

```
txtName.Text = htData["Name"].ToString();
txtAddress.Text = htData["Address"].ToString();
```

Doing this same thing for 60 values is time taking and inefficient.
is there a way to directly get the key and then set the value.

**Just like intellisense in vs.**

For example:

```
txtName.Text = htData.Name.Value.ToString();
txtAddress.Text = htData.Address.Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck with the Hashtable there is not much you can do. I would suggest switching to the Dictionary class.

You could then make the Key an Enumeration:

public enum DataType
{
   Name,
   Adress,
   ...
}

Or you could make an Object with 60 Properties, without using a Dictionary.
If you are stuck with the Hashtable, you could still use an Enumeration, with ToString().
A Hashtable will never provide "nice" code though.